# Python subprocess and shell input redirection

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, subprocess, io-redirection

On a unix command line I can do:

```
paste <(echo A) <(echo B)
```

However, when I try to do this:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('paste <(echo A) <(echo B)', shell = True)
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `paste <(echo A) <(echo B)'
```

Is it not possible to do shell input redirection with the subprocess module?

Comment: That's probably running `/bin/sh` as your shell which doesn't do that. You need to try to force it to use `/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks Etan! I added executable='/bin/bash' and it worked! Will you leave an answer?

Comment: have you given the **os.system('paste <(echo A) <(echo B)')** a try..?

Comment: Olu, that one fails as well. The subprocess docs reads: "This module intends to replace several older modules and functions: os.system"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many things by default use `/bin/sh` as the shell of choice. `/bin/sh` is often not bash.

The `/bin/sh` on your system most likely does not support process substitution.

Convince `subprocess.call` to use `/bin/bash` as the shell instead and it should work.

Comment: Thank you again. This did the trick: subprocess.call('paste <(echo A) <(echo B)', shell = True, executable='/bin/bash')

Comment: @tommy.carstensen: even `/bin/bash` if called using name `/bin/sh` may use different compatibility mode i.e., no process substitutions.